# A quick question on general mathematics

Tags: recreational-mathematics, contest-math

I have the following question that I am currently unable to satisfactorily answer myself.

My question is:

Does the inequality

$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a} < \frac{f(a)}{f(b)} + \frac{f(b)}{f(a)}\tag{*}$$

imply that $a < b$, in general (i.e., for ALL functions $f$)?

If the answer to my question is NO, under what conditions on the function $f$ is it true that inequality (***) implies $b < a$?

Comment: @André Nicolas, please see my latest comment below your answer, which I have already accepted - thank you!  :)

Comment: @André Nicolas, would you be kind enough as to shoot me an e-mail, as I could not determine your e-mail address from a quick web search?  My e-mail address is contained in my paper in JIS.  Thanks!  (I just want to show you what this question is for, and what I have done so far...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given inequality is **symmetric** in $a$ and $b$. So if it holds for some pair $(a,b)$, it also holds for the pair $(b,a)$. Thus it cannot force $a\lt b$.

Comment: And to answer the question, the given inequality will **never** imply $a<b$, unless the inequality is absurd (i.e., if holds for no pair $(a,b)$ at all; ex falso sequitur quodlibet).

Comment: Thanks Andrei, thanks Marc!

Comment: @André Nicolas, just a quick follow-up to your answer:  How about if we have the added condition that $\frac{f(a)}{a} < \frac{f(b)}{b}$?  Note that this last inequality is no longer symmetric.