# A follow-up question on an arithmetic function satisfying a certain inequality

Tags: recreational-mathematics, contest-math

In the MSE question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303756/a-quick-question-on-general-mathematics), I asked whether the inequality:

$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a} < \frac{f(a)}{f(b)} + \frac{f(b)}{f(a)}$$

would imply $a < b$ (where $f(x) \in \mathbb{N}$ is a function for $x \in \mathbb{N}$), if $\gcd(a, b) = 1$.  For the example I'm considering, I actually have $f(1) = 1$ and $f$ multiplicative (i.e., $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$ whenever $\gcd(m, n) = 1$).  (In fact, I do have $f(x) = \sigma_{1}(x)$, where $\sigma_{1}$ is the sum-of-divisors function.)

It turned out (from the subsequent answer by [André Nicolas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andre-nicolas) and a comment by [Marc van Leeuwen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/18880/marc-van-leeuwen)) that the first inequality cannot force the second, and that the first cannot imply the second unless the (first?) inequality is absurd (i.e., if it holds for no pair $(a,b)$ at all; ex falso sequitur quodlibet).

Now my follow-up question is this:  Will the statements from the previous paragraph still be true if we have the added condition that

$$\frac{f(a)}{f(b)} < \frac{a}{b}?$$

Edit [Feb 19 2013] - From a subsequent comment by [Ivan Loh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/61044/ivan-loh), it turns out that if

$$\frac{f(a)}{f(b)} < \frac{b}{a}$$

is also true, then the conclusion that I require will not necessarily follow, granted $a$ and $b$ are prime powers.

What will happen if $a = q^k$ where $q$ is prime and $b$ is a (fairly large) composite number?

Comment: Nope, counter-example: $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: Thanks @achille hui -- however, for the example I'm considering, I actually also require that $f(x) \in \mathbb{N}$.  Editing my question further to reflect this update.

Comment: Still no. Consider any function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(1)>2f(2)$. Then consider $a=2, b=1$. Note that $\frac{2}{1}+\frac{1}{2}<\frac{f(2)}{f(1)}+\frac{f(1)}{f(2)}$ and $\frac{f(2)}{f(1)}<\frac{2}{1}$ but $2>1$.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Loh.  For the example I'm considering, I actually have $f(1) = 1$ and $f$ multiplicative (i.e., $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$ whenever $\gcd(m, n) = 1$).  Editing my question now to reflect this update.

Comment: Please make the title more descriptive.

Comment: @${\mathbb{R}}^n$, doing so now.

Comment: Still no. Note that a multiplicative function is uniquely determined by its values at the prime powers. Consider any multiplicative function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that for some primes powers $p^m, q^n$ with $p^m<q^n$, we have $\frac{f(p^m)}{f(q^n)}>\frac{q^n}{p^m}$. Then consider $a=q^n, q=p^m$. Note that $\frac{q^n}{p^m}+\frac{p^m}{q^n}<\frac{f(q^n)}{f(p^m)}+\frac{f(p^m)}{f(q^n)}$ and $\frac{f(q^n)}{f(p^m)}<\frac{q^n}{p^m}$ but $q^n>p^m$. Maybe you would like to explicitly state the example you are considering, instead of adding restrictions one by one?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comment @Ivan Loh.  I will be providing the explicit example I am considering in a while.

Comment: Did you try small cases? Consider the simple counterexample $a=7, b=6, \frac{\sigma_1(7)}{\sigma_1(6)}<\frac{6}{7}<\frac{7}{6}, \frac{7}{6}+\frac{6}{7}<\frac{\sigma_1(7)}{\sigma_1(6)}+\frac{\sigma_1(6)}{\sigma_1(7)}, 7>6$. Clearly when $b$ is composite, you are more likely to get a counterexample to $a<b$.

Comment: Unless $xf(x)$ is a non-decreasing function of $x$, you will always get counter examples in the form $a>b, af(a)<bf(b)$.

Comment: My profuse thanks, @Ivan Loh!  Can you write/consolidate your last three (3) comments into an actual answer so that I may be able to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a consolidation of my comments into an answer:

A multiplicative function is uniquely determined by its values at the prime powers. Consider any multiplicative function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that for some prime powers $p^m, q^n$ with $p^m<q^n$, we have $\frac{f(q^n)}{f(p^m)}<\frac{p^m}{q^n}$.

Then we can take $a=q^n, b=p^m$, and we get 
$$\frac{q^n}{p^m}+\frac{p^m}{q^n}<\frac{f(q^n)}{f(p^m)}+\frac{f(p^m)}{f(q^n)} \; \text{and} \; \frac{f(q^n)}{f(p^m)}<\frac{p^m}{q^n}<\frac{q^n}{p^m}$$

but $a>b$, giving a counterexample to the claim.

For the explicit example $\sigma_1{(x)}$, trying small cases gives the counter example $a=7, b=6$, since 
$$\frac{7}{6}+\frac{6}{7}<\frac{\sigma_1{(7)}}{\sigma_1{(6)}}+\frac{\sigma_1{(6)}}{\sigma_1{(7)}} \; \text{and} \; \frac{\sigma_1{(7)}}{\sigma_1{(6)}}<\frac{6}{7}<\frac{7}{6}$$

but $7>6$, giving a counterexample to the claim.

In general, all counterexamples must satisfy 3 conditions:

$$a>b, \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}<\frac{f(a)}{f(b)}+\frac{f(b)}{f(a)}, \frac{f(a)}{f(b)}<\frac{a}{b}$$

We must necessarily have $$a>b, \frac{f(a)}{f(b)}<\frac{b}{a}<\frac{a}{b}$$
This is equivalent to $af(a)<bf(b)$ for $a>b$.

Thus your claim is correct if and only if $xf(x)$ is a non-decreasing function of $x$.